# Subspaces and intersections

Tags: combinatorics, finite-geometry

Stuck in step 3! See my sketch of proof below the theorem I am trying to prove:
Any other approach is welcome!

Theorem: Let $W$ be a k-dimensional subspace of $V$.  The number of ${k'}$-dimensional subspaces of $V$ which intersect $W$ in an i-dimensional subspace is given by $$q^{(k'-i)(k-i)} {n-k \brack k'-i}_q{k\brack i}_q$$ 
Proof (Draft)

Step 1: Choose an i-dimensional subspace of W : ${k\brack i}_q$ ways

Step 2: Choose $(k'-i)$-dimensional subspace of $V\setminus W$ :${n-k \brack k'-i}_q$ ways

Step 3:  How do we get the first term ($q^{(k'-i)(k-i)}$)??

P.S: this theorem was mentioned without proof in preliminaries on the paper I am studying (on some codes for distributed storage systems: "https://arxiv.org/abs/1701.07501"). In the paper there is a small section about Gaussian coefficient.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.

Comment: My thought is that $q^{(k' - i)(k - i)}$ accounts for the fact that there isn't a unique complementary subspace to the given $k$-dimensional one.

Comment: Morgan: I found this as a statement in a paper I study for Array codes constructed from Subspaces ( https://arxiv.org/abs/1701.0750  relation (4)). It was in a subsection about Gaussian coefficient in preliminaries. I would like to include the proof for my dissertation. Any tool would be ok I guess... Do you know how to prove it using quotient space? I am not familiar but may I have your sketch of proof? I can study about quotient space.

Comment: @Trevor: Any rough idea about the exponent $ (k'-i)(k-i)$?

Answer (score 0):

First recall that
$$(q^n - 1) \cdots (q^n - q^{k - 1})$$
counts the number of ways to pick a linearly independent set of $k$-vectors in a vector space of size $q^n$. This over-counts the number of $k$-dimensional subspaces because two linearly independent sets may span the same subspace.

The quantity
$$(q^k - 1) \cdots (q^k - q^{k - 1}) $$
counts the number of ways to pick a basis (linearly independent set of size $k$) for a given vector space of size $q^k$. Thus the number of $k$-dimensional subsets of a vector space of size $q^n$ is

$$ \frac{(q^n - 1) \cdots (q^n - q^{k - 1})}{(q^k - 1) \cdots (q^k - q^{k - 1})} = \begin{bmatrix} n \\ k \end{bmatrix}_q.$$

---

Now let $V$ be a given vector space of size $q^n$ and let $W$ be a fixed $k$-dimensional subspace of $V$. We know that there are $q^n - q^k$ vectors in $V \setminus W$. Thus we can pick a linearly independent set of size $k' - i$ from them in

$$ (q^n - q^k)(q^n - q^{k + 1}) \cdots (q^n - q^{k + k' - i - 1})$$

ways. We can factor out a $q^k$ from each of the $k' - i$ multiplicands to get

$$ q^{k(k' - i)} (q^{n - k} - 1)(q^{n - k} - q) \cdots (q^{n - k} - q^{k' - i - 1}). $$

Notice that we are over-counting by a factor of

$$ q^{i(k' - i)} (q^{k' - i} - 1) \cdots (q^{k' - i} - q^{k' - i - 1}). $$

Distributing a $q^i$ to each term gives

$$ (q^{k'} - q^{i}) \cdots (q^{k'} - q^{k' - 1}). \tag{$*$}$$

If $W'$ is the subspace of size $q^{k'}$ that we are interested in then $(*)$ tells us the number of ways to pick a set of $k' - i$ linearly independent vectors in $W'$. This counts the number of ways to extend a basis for $W' \cap W$ to a basis for $W$.

Correcting for this we have

$$ \begin{bmatrix} k \\ i \end{bmatrix}_q $$

ways to pick an $i$-dimensional subspace from $W$, times

$$ (q^n - q^k) \cdots (q^n - q^{k + k' - i - 1}) $$

ways to pick a linearly independent set that extends the $i$-dimensional subspace to a $k'$-dimensional one, $W'$. We divide by

$$ (q^{k'} - q^{i}) \cdots (q^{k'} - q^{k' - 1}) $$

which corrects for the fact that multiple choices of linearly independent sets give the same $W'$.

Hence in total we have

\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix} k \\ i \end{bmatrix}_q \frac{(q^n - q^k) \cdots (q^n - q^{k + k' - i - 1})}{(q^{k'} - q^{i}) \cdots (q^{k'} - q^{k' - 1})} &= \begin{bmatrix} k \\ i \end{bmatrix}_q \frac{q^{k(k' - i)} (q^{n - k} - 1) \cdots (q^{n - k} - q^{k' - i - 1})}{q^{i(k' - i)} (q^{k' - i} - 1) \cdots (q^{k' - i} - q^{k' - i - 1})} \\
&= q^{(k' - i)(k - i)} \begin{bmatrix} n - k \\ k' - i \end{bmatrix}_q \begin{bmatrix} k \\ i \end{bmatrix}_q.
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

If you follow the [reference](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/5695131/) associated with this claim, you can find the key result contained in the proof of Lemma 7, namely that given an $n$-dimensional subspace $X$, and an $i$-dimensional subspace $Z \subset X$, the number of $j$-spaces $Y$ with $Y \cap X = Z$ is given by $q^{(j-i)(k-i)}{n-k \brack j-i}_{q}$.

This count is obtained by counting the number of ways to complete the basis for $Y$ from a basis for $Z$: you have $q^{n} - q^{k}$ choices for the first additional vector (total number of vectors outside $X$), then you have $q^{n} - q^{k+1}$ choices for the next, $\ldots$, out to $q^{n} - q^{k+j-i-1}$. Then you need to divide by the total number of ways to complete a basis for a specific $Y$ from the basis for $Z$. I'll leave the reference to complete the details for this method of proof.

Comment: I will definitely do. Thank you!!